# jQuery .length returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to count a div with the class of "element" inside another div with the class of "parent". This is the HTML structure:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
</div>
```

The .length array / property works fine like this with jQuery:

```js
$("div.parent > div.element").length;
```

If I copy and paste the code above into the Chrome console I get 2 as a result, which is correct.
But if I try to make it a variable:

```js
var $numEx = $("div.parent > div.element").length;
```

It doesn't work correctly. For example, if I put numEx (or $numEx) in the console, I get 0 as a result...

This is the whole code together:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $numEx = $("div.examens > div.element").length;
</script>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">Element 1</div>
    <div class="element">Element 2</div>
 </div>
```

I have actually got some normal javascript before the jQuery...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `$("div.parent > div.element").length`?

Comment: Where is `div.examens`? Do you not mean `div.parent`? Are you sure you're using the exact same selector in both expressions?

Comment: Oops yeah sorry I changed it now

Comment: put the whole code together, the order is important .. the JS before or after will lead to different result and we need to see how you are doing

Comment: What? How do you mean together? @TemaniAfif

Comment: actually you shared the HTML alone and the JS alone, we don't know when you are calling the JS  .. we need to see all the code as one block

Comment: Did you put your js code inside $(document).ready()?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Done

Comment: and you have the issue .. you are calling the JS before the HTML, you need to call it after

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh okay thank you very much now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to reach the property of an element before its properties are available through Jquery. @osama had mentioned this in a comment.You can either place the script tag at the bottom of your Document or inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`. This function will let the document object model render before executing your script.